# package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist (maven)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, import, package

My first time using Java, I'm trying to use the ArrayUtils class form commons lang. I'm using maven with eclipse on mac.

I believe I've installed commons lang correctly in the pom.xml file-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.name</groupId>
  <artifactId>cellular-automata</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And I can see the package in the file directory-
[file directory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxMvF.png)

My first two line in my App.java are-

```
package com.name;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;
```

But I get this error when I try to run my code-

```
package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like it runs through eclipse but not through the terminal. Anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

Your scope should not be `provided` unless you're deploying to a host where it will, somehow, already **be** provided. Use `compile` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm sure its important but I don't think that was the source of my problem (see my comment above)